# set default selected node to be root when the jstree loads

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have the following jquery code that takes advantage of jstree plugin to build the tree, search a and select the tree. when I user selects a node, it opens up a new browser tab. When I load the first page the first time, I need root top root node to be select as a default. I tried initially_select under ui, but it is not working. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#tree").jstree({  
        "xml_data" : {  
             "ajax" :   {  
                 "url" : "jstree.xml" 
                      },  
                "xsl" : "nest"
                        },  
            "themes" : {  

                "theme" : "classic",  
                "dots" : true,  
                "icons" : true 

                        },  
            "ui":       {
                "initially_select" : [ "root" ]
                "save_selected" : false
                        },

            "search" :  {  

                    "case_insensitive" : true,  
                    "ajax" : {  
                     "url" : "jstree.xml" 
                            }  
                        }, 
    "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types", "search", "cookies"] 

    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
        $("#tree").jstree("toggle_node", data.rslt.obj);

        var isTeamNode = false;
        var node_id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
            if (node_id.indexOf("team") >= 0)
                {
                    isTeamNode = true;
                    $.cookie("example", node_id, { path: '/', expires:7 });
                    window.open('new_tab.html', '_newtab');
                }
        });
```

Comment: you might post a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can play with your code more easily

Comment: @dnagirl, jsfiddle does not work for me. I think it is blocked. I tried the jstree developers suggestion about initially_select, that did not work.